# Non-updateable query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Since I am no hero in sql, I have created the following SQL statement through the design view in ms access.

```
SELECT tbl_comments.Comments, tbl_mfr0004.Delivery
FROM tbl_mfr0004 
INNER JOIN tbl_current_orders ON (tbl_mfr0004.MFR0004_ID = tbl_current_orders.MFR0004_ID)
INNER JOIN tbl_comments ON (tbl_current_orders.Current_orders_ID = tbl_comments.Current_orders_ID) 
WHERE (tbl_mfr0004.Delivery = get_gvStepDelivery());
```

The query has a double inner join, which is depicted in the following image:
[image]

The query works, and thus gives me the field `comments` from `tbl_comments` and the field `Delivery` from `tbl_mfr0004`.

[image]

The problem now is however, that this recordset is not updateable. Since I want this query in a userform to add comments this is a problem.
Unfortunately I don't know how to rewrite a query as complex as this one, and if it is even possible.

I was thinking about perhaps using a subquery to select the correct orderID, but unfortunately I didn't manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join is never updatable.

If you want an updatable query, perhaps you can rewrite it as an select with sub-selects in the select-list. I.e.

```
SELECT (SELECT tbl_comments.Comments
        FROM tbl_current_orders ON (tbl_mfr0004.MFR0004_ID = tbl_current_orders.MFR0004_ID)
            INNER JOIN tbl_comments ON (tbl_current_orders.Current_orders_ID = tbl_comments.Current_orders_ID),
       tbl_mfr0004.Delivery
FROM tbl_mfr0004 
WHERE (tbl_mfr0004.Delivery = get_gvStepDelivery());
```

If there are more than one comment for a delivery this query will raise an error!

Comment: So, if you put the join in the subquery, it becomes updatable? And there can only be one comment luckily.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved the problem via vba this time;
I already created the function get_gvStepDelivery() to get the delivery out of another subform, where on the `current` event, the global variable `gvStepDelivery` was assigned the value of `Me.Delivery`.

```
Public Function get_gvStepDelivery() As Long
    get_gvStepDelivery = gvStepDelivery
End Function
```

Now, I have created yet another function, which is a double `DLookup()` Of the `CurrentOrderID` with the `MFR0004_ID` and `Delivery`, since they are both unique.

```
Public Function getorderid(Delivery As Long) As Long
    getorderid = DLookup("Current_orders_ID", "tbl_current_orders", "[MFR0004_ID] = " & DLookup("MFR0004_ID", "tbl_mfr0004", "[Delivery] = " & Delivery))
End Function
```

This function is called in the query with `getorderid(get_gvStepDelivery())`.
The eventual SQL statement then became:

```
SELECT tbl_comments.Comments, tbl_comments.Current_orders_ID
FROM tbl_comments
WHERE (((tbl_comments.Current_orders_ID)=getorderID(get_gvStepDelivery())));
```

This works, and is updateable.

I am still wondering however, if it is possible to rewrite the query to get the desired result?